# Using join to retrieve a row from 2 tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM movie_time AS a,movie_db AS b, movie_actor AS c
WHERE a.Movie_ID = b.Movie_ID AND b.Movie_ID=c.Movie_ID 
      AND c.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID AND Movie_ID =17
```

Hi i am trying to use the join function to retrieve the row which is working *unless* when i put the `AND Movie_ID =17` clause i am not able to retrieve the row which corresponds to `Movie_ID =17`

I am using mySQL workbench. Can I also use the similar statement to also delete the particular row retreived?

The error:  `Error code 1052 Column 'Movie_ID' in where clause is ambiguos`

Comment: do you have any error message receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the alias `a.Movie_ID =17`:

```
SELECT * FROM movie_time AS a,movie_db AS b, movie_actor AS c
WHERE a.Movie_ID = b.Movie_ID AND b.Movie_ID=c.Movie_ID 
      AND c.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID AND a.Movie_ID =17
```

And for the delete (assuming you want to delete from `movie_time` table):

```
DELETE
    a
FROM 
    movie_time AS a 
INNER JOIN movie_db AS b
    ON a.Movie_ID = b.Movie_ID
INNER JOIN movie_actor AS c
    ON c.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
WHERE 
    a.Movie_ID =17
```

Comment: Thank you i am able to retrieve that row. How can i also modify the code to delete that particular row from all the tables?

Comment: would you mind if you look at my problem related to the delete statement here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592007/
Thanks :)

Comment: @DeepakTivari sorry but i saw it too late

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM movie_time AS a,movie_db AS b, movie_actor AS c
WHERE a.Movie_ID = b.Movie_ID AND b.Movie_ID=c.Movie_ID 
      AND c.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID AND a.Movie_ID =17
```

You have not specified alias name for Movie_ID =17 resulting in ambiguity. 
As all the mentioned tables have column Movie_id , SQL can't decide which tables Movie_id column you are refering to when using the statement Movie_id=17.
Change it to `a.Movie_ID =17` if you want `Movie_id=17` from table movie_time .

As a side note , you should do this by using INNER JOIN .

Comment: Thank you i am able to retrieve that row. How can i also modify the code to delete that particular row from all the tables?

Comment: From which table do you want to delete ?

Answer (score 1):

The answers about aliasing are correct. In addition to the fix, I'd also like to encourage you to use ANSI joins, which will clean up your `WHERE` clause and let you split the filtering logic (`Movie_ID = 17`) from the join logic (all the rest of the noise in the `WHERE` clause).

This will do the same as the queries above:

```
SELECT * FROM movie_time AS a
  INNER JOIN movie_db AS b ON a.Movie_ID = b.Movie_ID
  INNER JOIN movie_actor AS c ON b.Movie_ID=c.Movie_ID
  WHERE a.Movie_ID =17
```

You don't need the `AND c.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID` part of the `WHERE` because you're already joining `a` to `c` through `b`.

Comment: +1 for spotting the condition that is not needed , i've missed it

Comment: Thanks Stephan - that's one of the many benefits of the ANSI join syntax. +1 yourself for taking care of the `DELETE` question :)

Answer (score 0):

This returns more columns than you need but consider a syntax along these lines...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM movie_time mt
  JOIN movie_db m
    ON m.Movie_ID = mt.Movie_ID 
  JOIN movie_actor ma
    ON ma.Movie_ID = m.Movie_ID
 WHERE m.Movie_ID = 17;
```

Note that any "actorless" movies will not be returned!