# Having Foreign key constrain while deleting rows using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELETE
    a,b,c
FROM 
sp_movie.movie_db AS a
INNER JOIN sp_movie.movie_time AS b
      ON a.Movie_ID = b.Movie_ID
INNER JOIN sp_movie.movie_time AS c
      ON c.Movie_ID = a.Movie_ID
WHERE 
    a.Movie_ID = 29
```

I am trying to delete all the rows from all three tables which has the `Movie_ID = 29`

I even tried writing this 
`DELETE a FROM.....`

I am having an error : `Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sp_movie`.`movie_actor`, CONSTRAINT`2`FOREIGN KEY (`Movie_ID`) REFERENCES`movie_db`(`Movie_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting the foreign key referenced action to `on cascade` for both `time` and `actors` table

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple queries and delete the rows from `movie_time` first and then `movie_db` separately.  You could also use `SET foreign_key_checks = 0` before running the above query.

Comment: Or better yet, set the foreign key actions to `ON DELETE CASCADE` and then merely delete from the parent table, letting MySQL do the rest for you.

Comment: @eggyal That seems to be a good idea! Gotto check whats my settings for that

Comment: @eggyal that's not necessarily better yet; there may be circumstances where he doesn't want the delete to cascade; I think it's better to play it safe